# How to remove a Python service in Windows?

Tags: windows, python, service

I have a custom Python package which we are installing to several Windows platforms (XP, 2003, 2008).  During setup, this command is run which registers a service:

```
python.exe setup.py install
```

What is the correct way to remove services created this way?  I know that I can use sc.exe but should be a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, There should be no problem in removing the service with sc.

Also, Check in the add remove programs. Most packages that install in this way put entry in the add/remove programs in control panel.

Run the python.exe setup.py --help and see the output. or even just python.exe setup.py without any parameters. Most packeges will print uninstall information.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look inside setup.py, there might be a listing of verbs, one of which can be "uninstall" or "remove"

python code is extremely easy to read

Answer (score 1):

Removing services using sc.exe is perfectly fine and supported.

Answer (score 0):

Running

`python.exe setup.py remove`

worked for me. Note that I had to run from an Adminstrator's Command Prompt to either install or remove the service.

Answer (score 0):

Interact with services manager in cmd: (for help just type "sc" in cmd)

```
sc delete "YourServiceName"
```